# How to load multiple .hs files with only functions (no modules) into haskell ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I can load a single haskell file with a single function into ghci using `:l addOne.hs`

If I load another haskell file `:l addTwo.hs` it wipes the reference to the other and I get a `Variable not in scope: addOne` error when I try to call `addOne`

addOne.hs

```
addOne x = x + 1
```

addTwo.hs

```
addTwo x = x + 2
```

There are a few other posts that talk about loading multiple modules.  Is the only way to achieve the above to convert them to modules and call

```
> :load Module1 Module2
> :module Module1 Module2
```

Comment: Maybe `:script filename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-990005.1

> An abbreviated form of module, consisting only of the module body, is permitted. If this is used, the header is assumed to be `module Main(main) where`.

I don't think you can have two identically named modules loaded into `ghci` (the real name of the module; you can have aliased qualified imports).

Comment: ah, that explains the error I received when I tried to import them both at the same time too.  It makes sense.  Many thanks :-)